# Two vimfiles directories. Where do I install my plugins?

Tags: windows, vim

I'm using Windows 10.

I want to give Vim another shot after having some troubles with it in the past. I'm eager to learn it, but I'm confused. I gave a pretty thorough search to find my answer before I resorted to posting this here, but what is the **proper** way to install my vim plugins. I see two `vimfiles` folders in two different directories.

One in the `$HOME` directory.

`C:\User\[USERNAME]\vimfiles`

And one in the installation directory.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles`

Is there a reason for there being two of these ? What's the best directory to install my plugins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to `'runtimepath'` param. Read `:help 'runtimepath'` for more info . `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles` is system folder with default plugins which are shipped with vim itself. `C:\User\[USERNAME]\vimfiles` is your local runtimepath. And there you should put your plugins. This way if you have multiple users they all will have own vim environment to work in. If you want you can even set different `runtimepath` but this is whole another question))

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

`C:\User\[USERNAME]\vimfiles` is **your** vim runtime files and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles` is **Vim**'s runtime files. As long as a feature is present in your vim runtime files and vim request it, it will load them and if its not present there, then it will fallback to his runtime path to find it (i.e. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles` ). So you should always install your plugins, colorschemes, syntaxes, ... in your vim runtime files and also back it up in a safe place and never touch vim's runtime files.